# Why does this image not line up in the center of the table vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

I have a 20px by 20px image that is showing up on the upper left of an empty table:

```
<table width="100px">
    <tr>
        <td width='100%' align='center' valign='center'>
            <img id='redimg' src='/images/redimg.gif'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

How do I get it to appear in the center of the table both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: Please don't tell me your using to code your site.

Comment: td will be 100% width unless you tell it not to be

Comment: @hunter a minor correction, but one worth making: a `tr` element will be divided equally amongst its `td` descendants unless otherwise defined. So *one* `td` in a row will be 100% width, in a row with *two* `td`s, each `td` will be 50% by default, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `valign` attribute to the `tr` element, then change "center" to "middle".

Then delete it all and use CSS ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try this HTML

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img id='redimg' src='/images/redimg.gif'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

and this CSS

```
.mytable
{
    width: 100px;
}

.mytable td
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```